# Zend doctrine Session issue

Tags: zend-framework, session, doctrine

I am having issues while trying to set up a Session Save Handler using Doctrine in Zend.

What I am trying to do is to make [this](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Doctrine+-+Matthew+Lurz) proposal work. I followed the instruction as follow:-

- class Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Doctrine entered in proper direcotry
- table set up ready
- Doctrine Model ready
- bootstrap ready

Still i get this error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Exception' with message 'Couldn't find class Session' in....
```

I am not sure where the problem is or what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Doctrine ORM (I still use the 1.x version), you can fix this error by replacing the line 289:

```
$session = new Session();
```

with this:

```
$session = new $this->_tableName;
```

Comment: Hello, I did give up on it and using the Zend way. Never the less I tried your suggestion but still got the same error.